# Count row divided by count row

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have some problem with MySQL syntax in CI this is my table

```
id_data | nama_depan | nama_belakang | gender | luas_lantai | jenis_lantai 
| status
```

I already tried code bellow and show error

> Message: Object of class CI_DB_mysqli_result could not be converted to
>   int

```
public function getStatus1($status){ 
$str = "SELECT count(status) 
        FROM data_latih WHERE status = 1 "; 

$str1 = "SELECT count(status) 
         FROM data_latih ";

    $query = $this->db->query($str); 
    $query1 = $this->db->query($str1);

    return $query / $query1;
}
```

expected output is decimal number of count status = 1 divided by count all rows

EDIT : Found the answer, thank you so much guys i'm new in programming so bear with me :)))

Comment: Please try return (array_merge($query, $query1) in function

Comment: The error message is pretty clear, you have an object of the `CI_DB_mysqli_result` class. To get the actual numbers you would have to fetch a row from that result.

Comment: Is the status field either `0` or `1`, and never anything else? If so, you can use `AVG()` (the average is the sum divided by the number of rows).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to divide an Object by the Object which does not make any sense, Try this CI way,

```
public function getStatus1($status){ 

$this->db->count_all_results('data_latih '); 
$this->db->where('status ', '1');
$this->db->from('data_latih ');
$result1 = (float)$this->db->count_all_results();

$result2 = (float)$this->db->count_all('data_latih'); 

    return $result1 / $result2 ;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can actually handle this with a single query:

```
SELECT
    SUM(status = 1) / COUNT(status) AS result
FROM data_latih;
```

Regarding your PHP code, I would recommend assigning aliases to the various counts, and then accessing those aliases.

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(status = 1) / COUNT(status) AS result FROM data_latih";
$result = $this->db->query($sql);
if ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
    echo $row['result'];
}
```